# How to properly install missing firmware during Debian setup

Tags: debian, usb-drive, debian-installer, firmware

This issue has followed me over the years, every once in a while I resolved it, but I never found the one solution.

Most of the times, the issue is a missing wireless firmware, in the current instance [b43/ucode16_mimo.fw](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx).

I usually create the install drive with `dd if=./debian.iso of=/dev/sdb`.

Now in the past, I've tried to find the firmware file and copy it onto a USB flash drive. The first issues were:

- I couldn't find the exact, required file (e.g. b43/ucode16_mimo.fw). I believe that [this included the missing firmware](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/) file once, but didn't work this time.
- The install medium is read-only, so I used a second USB drive, where I don't know if it's accepted or not.
- I have no clue where to place the files on the USB drive.. is it in `/`, `/firmware/`,  `/lib/firmware` or somewhere entirely else?

Lately I failed there and wasn't able to add the firmware during the setup, that's where I found the [images with firmware included](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/), which felt like a holy savior at this point.

But that didn't change a thing, I was prompted with the same error about missing firmware again.

**TL;DR and my question:**

How do I correctly add missing firmware during a Debian setup and where do I find the suggested firmware files?